# Code in a workbook making unwanted changes on another when both are open

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that timestamps items every time I change a cell.

Sometimes when I take information off of that workbook and paste it onto another that I have open, I see random time stamps on the uncoded workbook. It seems my code is "bleeding " onto the other workbook.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xDateColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range
xCellColumn = 11
xTimeColumn = 9
xDateColumn = 10
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
       Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Date
       Cells(xRow, xDateColumn) = Time()
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
        For Each xRg In xDPRg
            If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Date
            End If
        Next
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: A couple of things I can see - you change a value in column K, the `SheetChange` event fires.... the code adds a date into column I on the sheet which is a change in value so the `SheetChange` event fires and tries to run the `Else` part of the code.  After that's finished it returns to the first event and adds the `Time` which changes a value in column J so the event fires again..... `Application.EnableEvents = False` turns that off.  Remember to turn it back on before exiting the procedure.

Comment: `Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Date` is not specific about which sheet to put the date in so it puts it on the currently activesheet.  Usually with a `SheetChange` you're on the correct sheet, but I'm guessing something happens while the code is running that changes the sheet?  Try using `Target.Parent.Cells(....)` which will refer to the sheet that Target is relevant to.

Comment: Also, after adding the `Application.EnableEvents` you'll need to manually turn it back on in the Immediate window if your code stops before it reaches the line that turns it back on.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook actually `Sh.Cells(…)` because `Target.Parent` is `Sh` :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook so I am constantly working on multiple workbooks at the same time, and i have the code running s it works on every sheet in the workbook on purpose. can i make sure its only running the process on the sheet that triggers it?

Comment: As @Peh corrected me.... `Sh` is the sheet that the event fires on so use `sh.cells`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure there is never a `Cells`, `Range`, `Columns` or `Rows` object in your code that has no worksheet referenced. In this code `Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn)` is the same as `ActiveSheet.Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn)` but the sheet the code runs in is `sh` and this might not be the `ActiveSheet`. Make sure you always referecne the sheet.
2. `Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range` will only declare the variable `xRg As Range` but `xDPRg As Variant`. In VBA you need to declare a type for **every** variable or it is `Variant` by default. To make them both of type `Range` you need to declare `Dim xDPRg As Range, xRg As Range` or each in one line.
3. Row and column counting variables need to be of type `Long` there are more rows in Excel than `Integer` can handle.
4. You need to disable events when writing to cells in the `Workbook_SheetChange` otherwise every change will run anotehr `Workbook_SheetChange` event and so you get an endless loop. Also make sure to enable events in any case of an error or they will be turned off in your entire Excel until you close Excel and reopen it.
5. Never turn of error reporting using `On Error Resume Next` witout turning it on again right after the line where you expect an error to occur! This is very dangerous because if there are any errors that you do not expect you will not see them and if you don't see them you cannot fix them and therefore your code will not work. Never go blind!
6. Variables that you set hardcoded to a value are constants and therefore should be declared as `Const`.

So it has to look something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Const xCellColumn As Long = 11
    Const xTimeColumn As Long = 9
    Const xDateColumn As Long = 10
    
    Dim xRow As Long
    xRow = Target.Row
    
    Dim xCol As Long
    xCol = Target.Column
    
    On Error GoTo ENABLE_EVENTS ' make sure in case of an error events will be turned on again!
    Application.EnableEvents = False  ' disable events or you will get a endless loop when changing cells
    
    If Target.Text <> vbNullString Then
        If xCol = xCellColumn Then
           Sh.Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Date
           Sh.Cells(xRow, xDateColumn) = Time()
        Else
            Dim xDPRg As Range
            On Error Resume Next  ' we expect an error in the next row if there is no dependents so we stop error reporting
            Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
            On Error GoTo ENABLE_EVENTS ' make sure to turn error reporting on again and enable events if unexpected errors occur
            
            Dim xRg As Range
            For Each xRg In xDPRg
                If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                    Sh.Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Date
                End If
            Next xRg
        End If
    End If
     ENABLE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Err.Raise Err.Number ' report the error or you will not notice if there are errors End Sub
```